# Last Item is not showing in scroll view xml android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm encountering an issue with my Android app layout where the last item is not fully shown when the app is running. I have a layout structure that includes multiple items, but the last one seems to be cut off or not fully displayed. How can I ensure that all items in my layout are fully visible when the app is running?

Here's a simplified version of my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".PartnerInfosActivity">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="32dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_ppic_iv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/partner" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radius"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_name_tv_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                    android:text="Partner Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark2"
                    android:textSize="32sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_desc_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_regular"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:text="this is a brief descreption of the partner for example you can say that the partner is located at and has a lot functionalaties and you are going to like it if you want enjoy"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark4"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_phone_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_medium"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="0793802237"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark3"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/phone"
                    app:drawableTint="@color/dark5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_location_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_medium"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Tlemcen, Hennaya"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark3"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/location"
                    app:drawableTint="@color/dark5" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/browse_lost_items_cv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="16dp">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/items_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                                android:text="Browse items"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/two_arrows"
                            app:tint="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/report_lost_item_cv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/report" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                                android:text="Report items"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/two_arrows"
                            app:tint="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/report_lost_item_cv2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/report" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                                android:text="Report items"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/two_arrows"
                            app:tint="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/report_lost_item_cv3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/report" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                                android:text="Report items"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/two_arrows"
                            app:tint="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the children of your first `LinearLayout` are using weights to define how match space will occupy on the screen instead of wrapping to its contents. Therefore the `CardView` child with the `android:layout_weight="1"` will take the 1/3 of your screen and the `LinearLayout` child with the `android:layout_weight="2"` will take the remaining 2/3 of your screen. In your case the last item exceeds the 2/3 of your screen and thats why the last item is not visible. This issue can be avoid by using the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to the children instead of weights.

Below is the modified xml version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".PartnerInfosActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="32dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_ppic_iv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/partner" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_radius"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_name_tv_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                    android:text="Partner Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark2"
                    android:textSize="32sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_desc_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_regular"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:text="this is a brief descreption of the partner for example you can say that the partner is located at and has a lot functionalaties and you are going to like it if you want enjoy"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark4"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_phone_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_medium"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="0793802237"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark3"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/phone"
                    app:drawableTint="@color/dark5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_location_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_medium"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Tlemcen, Hennaya"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark3"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/location"
                    app:drawableTint="@color/dark5" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/browse_lost_items_cv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="16dp">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/items_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                                android:text="Browse items"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/two_arrows"
                            app:tint="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/report_lost_item_cv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/report" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                                android:text="Report items"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/two_arrows"
                            app:tint="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/report_lost_item_cv2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/report" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                                android:text="Report items"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/two_arrows"
                            app:tint="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/report_lost_item_cv3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/report" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_bold"
                                android:text="Report items"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/two_arrows"
                            app:tint="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```